# Why am I getting extra text nodes as child nodes of root node?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I want to print the child elements of the root node. This is my XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Comment-->
<company>
   <staff id="1001">
       <firstname>yong</firstname>
       <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
       <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
       <salary>100000</salary>
   </staff>
   <staff id="2001">
       <firstname>low</firstname>
       <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
       <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
       <salary>200000</salary>
   </staff>
</company>
```

According to my understanding, root node is 'company' and its child nodes must be 'staff' and 'staff' (as there are 'staff' nodes 2 times). But when I am trying to get them through my java code I am getting 5 child nodes. Where are the 3 extra text nodes coming from?

Java Code:

```
package com.training.xml;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ReadingXML {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        File file = new File("D:\\TestFile.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("root element: " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        Node rootNode = doc.getDocumentElement(); 
        System.out.println("root: " + rootNode.getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = rootNode.getChildNodes(); 

        for(int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println("node name: " + nList.item(i).getNodeName() );
        }           
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
root element: company
root: company
node name: #text
node name: staff
node name: #text
node name: staff
node name: #text
```

Why the three text nodes are coming over here?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> Why the three text nodes are coming over here ?

They're the whitespace between the child *elements*. If you only want the child elements, you should just ignore nodes of other types:

```
for (int i = 0;i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nList.item(i);
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        System.out.println("node name: " + node.getNodeName());
    }
}
```

Or you could change your document to not have that whitespace.

Or you could use a different XML API which allows you to easily ask for just elements. (The DOM API is a pain in various ways.)

If you only want to ignore element content whitespace, you can use [`Text.isElementContentWhitespace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Text.html#isElementContentWhitespace%28%29).

Comment: Thanks! It worked :) One more thing, it is taking newline character as a text node. Newline char is a whitespace? Is there any way to get only the child elements and not the text nodes as output because, I have to put newline chars in my XML file and it is showing newline chars as text nodes.

Comment: @VikasMangal: Yes, line breaks are whitespace. My answer includes code to only look at elements.

Comment: I had same issue in javascript and this solution worked for it too :D

Comment: I had the same issue with oracle's xmlparserverV2 .jar. It worked for me too after resolving the whitespace issue. parser.setPreserveWhitespace(false);

Comment: I found one option that seems to set the parser ignore whitespace, however, it seems not working after my test: `dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    dbFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);` Any ideas?

Comment: @K.Symbol: I would suggest creating a new question with a [mcve] and more detail than "it seems not working".