# XML parse with clojure.data.xml. How to omit "\n " items from :content during "parse"

Tags: xml, parsing, clojure

First I parsed XML file as

```clj
(def xtest (slurp "./resources/smallXMLTest.xml"))
(def way1 (clojure.xml/parse xtest))
(:content way1)
```

And do NOT have any "\n   " items in `:content` hashmap.

But when I parse XML like this, with help of `clojure.data.xml`

```clj
(def way2 (clojure.data.xml/parse-str xtest))
(:content way2)
```

then I got "\n    " strings in each non-leaf `:content` element in `way2` var, between each couple of inner XMLElements :(

Is there a way to avoid these "\n    " strings?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47475799 might help.

Answer (score 4):

There's an undocumented option :skip-whitespace to all the parsers available in clojure.data.xml.

```
(clojure.xml/parse-str whitespacey-str :skip-whitespace true)
;; => :content without spurious "\n"s
```

Documentation bug is here https://clojure.atlassian.net/browse/DXML-63

Answer (score 1):

I recently added 2 XML parsers to [the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo), one based on `clojure.data.xml` and the other based on `tagsoup`.  In both cases, I remove whitespace nodes by default.  Here is [the operative function](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/src/clj/tupelo/parse/xml.clj#L105):

```
(defn enlive-remove-whitespace
  "Removes whilespace strings from Enlive data :content vectors."
  [item]
  (if (and (map? item) ; Enlive data parsed from XML may has raw strings (esp. whitespace) embedded in it
        (contains-key? item :tag)) ; when parsing html, may get non-enlive nodes like {:type :comment, :data "..."}
    (let [content-new (cond-it-> (:content item)
                        (or (nil? it) (empty? it)) []
                        :then (drop-if (fn [arg]
                                         (and (string? arg)
                                           (ts/whitespace? arg))) it)
                        :then (mapv enlive-remove-whitespace it))]
      (glue item {:content content-new}))
    item))
```

It is used like this for `tupelo.parse.xml`:

```
(s/defn parse       ; #todo fix docstring
  ([xml-input] (parse xml-input sax-parse-fn))
  ([xml-input parse-fn]
    (enlive-remove-whitespace
      (enlive-normalize
        (parse-raw xml-input parse-fn)))))
```

So you see you can use [the function `parse-raw`](https://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.parse.xml.html) if you don't want to normalize or whitespace-trim the resulting Enlive-format data.

Similar [choices for `parse` and `parse-raw`](https://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.parse.tagsoup.html) are available in the `tupelo.parse.tagsoup` namespace.

You can see usage examples [in the test ns](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/clj/tst/tupelo/parse/xml.clj):

```
(def xml-str "<foo>
                <name>John</name>
                <address>1 hacker way</address>
                <phone></phone>
                <school>
                    <name>Joe</name>
                    <state>CA</state>
                    <type>FOOBAR</type>
                </school>
                <college>
                    <name>mit</name>
                    <address></address>
                    <state>Denial</state>
                </college>
              </foo> ")

(def enlive-tree-normalized-nonblank
  {:tag     :foo,
   :attrs   {},
   :content [{:tag :name, :attrs {}, :content ["John"]}
             {:tag :address, :attrs {}, :content ["1 hacker way"]}
             {:tag :phone, :attrs {}, :content []}
             {:tag     :school,
              :attrs   {},
              :content [{:tag :name, :attrs {}, :content ["Joe"]}
                        {:tag :state, :attrs {}, :content ["CA"]}
                        {:tag :type, :attrs {}, :content ["FOOBAR"]}]}
             {:tag     :college,
              :attrs   {},
              :content [{:tag :name, :attrs {}, :content ["mit"]}
                        {:tag :address, :attrs {}, :content []}
                        {:tag :state, :attrs {}, :content ["Denial"]}]}]})
```

with result

```
(dotest  
  (let [xml-data              (xml/parse     (ts/string->stream xml-str))
        tagsoup-data          (tagsoup/parse (ts/string->stream xml-str))]
    (is= enlive-tree-normalized-nonblank xml-data)
    (is= enlive-tree-normalized-nonblank tagsoup-data) ))
```