# Appending XML data to an ArrayList

Tags: java, xml, arraylist, multidimensional-array, xml-parsing

I have created an XML parser to retrieve the information from an XML file to java, and then I am trying to store these data into an ArrayList in order to use the ArrayList for my methods.
It seems to work fine when I print it. However, I got a method called getAllRoutes *for some reason it returns the wrong number of routes*

[image]

Comment: please add example how you using method getAllRoutes()

Comment: there is a marker responsible for running and testing my methods, and gives me feedback for each method, the feedback for getAllRoutes(); is: _The test failed because the wrong number of routes was returned by getAllRoutes() after loading data_
@Daniyar

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this helps Khaled.

Try this:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class Main {
  public static Iterable<Node> iterable(final NodeList nodeList) {
    return () -> new Iterator<Node>() {

        private int index = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return index < nodeList.getLength();
        }

        @Override
        public Node next() {
            if (!hasNext())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            return nodeList.item(index++); 
        }
    };
  }
  private static List<String> evaluateXPath(Document document, String xpathExpression)
  {
        // Create XPathFactory object
        XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

        // Create XPath object
        XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        try
        {
            // Create XPathExpression object
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathExpression);

            // Evaluate expression result on XML document
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                values.add(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
            }

        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return values;
    }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Build DOM

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse("data.xml");

        //Create XPath

        XPathFactory xpathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpathfactory.newXPath();
        String xpathRoot = "//Routes/Route";
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathRoot);
        int i = 0;
        for (Node n : iterable((NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET))) {
          i++;
          String xpe2 = String.format("%s[%d]/%s/text()", xpathRoot, i, "FlightNumber");
          System.out.println("FxPe: " + xpe2);
          System.out.println("Flight Number: " + evaluateXPath(doc, xpe2).get(0));
           for (Node n2 : iterable(n.getChildNodes())) {
              System.out.println(n2.getTextContent());
           }

        }
  }
}
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/CraftyDizzyAddress)

Useful links:

- [1: Iterate through NodeList](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48153597/495157)
- [2: XPath CheatSheet](https://devhints.io/xpath)
- 3: Java XPath Example [a](https://howtodoinjava.com/xml/java-xpath-tutorial-example/) and [b](https://howtodoinjava.com/xml/java-xpath-expression-examples/)
- [4: NodeList Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html)
- [5: Node Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html)

And I would say. I your code:
 `Route r = new Route();` should be inside if statement 
`if (c.getNodeName().equals("Route"))`
The commented out add is in the right place - the other place is wrong.

Comment: I tried including  Route r = new Route(); inside the if statement but that did not work , now it says _the wrong number of routes was returned when running the method_ which means its actually returning a number but for some reason its wrong, while if i uncomment the commented **routes.add(r);** it throws for some reason a null pointer exception even after I tried what you suggested above of including the new route in the if statement    @JGFMK

Comment: i tried your XPath method, it works fine, however, what the best way yo populate that to my ArrayList so I can use it for getAllRoutes(); method?

Comment: You could create a new route object in the outer loop, populating all the properties of a route object, using an  array of property names, building  the xpath expression for each property. Then when all the properties are assigned to the route object, add it to the routes collection. I would have been inclined to generare a new ArrayList each time you processed the XML. Maybe even that was where the issue lied in your original code. In your original post, your commented out add method was the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

Please move

```
routes.add(r);
```

inside

```
if (c.getNodeName().equals("Route")) {
```

Comment: that has thrown this exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: additionally please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259742/why-am-i-getting-extra-text-nodes-as-child-nodes-of-root-node, for why there are 4 children of <Routes> element

Comment: if you are getting NullPointerException, please share that

Comment: there is a marker which tests my code and that's what it says " The test failed because an exception was thrown by the RouteDAO: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: the only way that line could throw an NullPointerException is **if routes is null**, but that's not the case here, as we initialized while declaration itself **routes**

Comment: check and run the code, here https://repl.it/repls/MountainousFrankLoop

Comment: I am not supposed to read as a string cuz I got a massive XML file

Comment: That was only for demo, you could use your original code there, which reads from file.